# Maintain the li width according to the content

Tags: html, css

Here, I am missing something basic.
**HTML**

```
Unordered List:
<ul>
    <li>Apple</li>
    <li>Ball</li>
    <li>Cat</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul li{
    background-color:#fcf;
    margin:5px;
    list-style:none;
}
```

[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/aLbsdkor/)
I want the *width* of **li** be according to the content but here the width is 100%(maybe). 
 Help Me!! 
 Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You could float and clear the list items like:

```
ul li{
    background-color:#fcf;
    margin:5px;
    list-style:none;
    float:left;
    clear:left;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/aLbsdkor/2/)**

Or wrap the list items in a span
Unordered List:

```
<ul>
    <li><span>Apple</span>
    </li>
    <li><span>Ball</span>
    </li>
    <li><span>Cat</span>
    </li>
</ul>
ul li {
    list-style:none;
}
ul li span {
    background-color:#fcf;
    margin:5px;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/g62knc0L/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. It accomplishes what you want, but I can't imagine this being all that practical.

**CSS**

```
ul li {
    background-color:#fcf;
    margin:5px;
    list-style:none;
    display:inline;
    float:left;
    clear:both
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ytL0rweo/

Answer (score 0):

By using: float or display:inline-block

```
ul li{
    background-color:#fcf;
    margin:5px;
    list-style:none;
    float:left;
}
```

OR

```
ul li{
        background-color:#fcf;
        margin:5px;
        list-style:none;
        display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Thankyou. what if text is center aligned and I want li to have line breaks.